# Why does Dart generics behave this way?

Tags: generics, dart

Why does the two checks evaluate to `true` in the following example?

```dart
class Horse {}

int main() {
    print(<int>[1,2] is List<Horse>);
    print(<Horse>[new Horse()] is List<int>);
}
```

Comment: `print(<A>[] is List<B>);` prints `true` when `A extends B` or `A implements B` (or `A` is `dynamic`).

Answer (score 0):

I get

```
Breaking on exception: type 'List<num>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' of 'list'.
```

When I change `<num>` to `<int>` or vice versa so that the assignment works
I get

> false

My Dart version:

> Dart VM version: 1.1.0-dev.5.9 (Mon Jan 13 09:41:04 2014) on "linux_x64"

Comment: I ran it on try.dartlang.org. Are you running in checked mode?

Comment: I tried on http://try.dartlang.org and I get `true` too. Seems to be a bug on the site. I run it locally from the Darteditor.

Comment: Peter von der Ahe is working on try.dartlang.org again. This bug should hopefully be fixed soon. See https://plus.google.com/+PetervonderAh%C3%A9/posts/2yBVzcrxT2T